# Can the roots of a linear combination of polynomials all have negative real part?

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, roots

I have $N$ monic polynomials of degree $(N-1)$, with complex unknown $x\in \mathbb{C}$: $\text{Pol}_{i}(x)$.

I take a linear combination of those polynomials, obtaining another polynomial of degree $(N-1)$: $\text{Pol}_{sum}(x)=\sum_{i}a_{i}\text{Pol}_{i}(x)$, with complex unknown $x\in \mathbb{C}$. I want to show that exists at least one linear combination with real coefficients $a_{i}\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\text{Pol}_{sum}(x)$ has no roots with positive real part.

P.S. I feel that the answer is positive and it has to do with the vector space of the polynomials of degree $(N-1)$ or less.

Comment: If all coefficients are real, then  *no root with poitive imaginary part*  is equivalent to *all roots are real*.

Comment: It was positive real part, my bad. Thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe the answer is: yes, because you can always write a wanted polynomial of degree $N-1$ as the linear combination of $N$ given polynomials? I am not sure about that

Comment: are the original $N$ monic polynomials with real coefficients or complex coefficients?